# How to rename all files one by one through find command?

Tags: bash, shell, file, find, rename

I want to append a string to each file printed by the find command . It prints each file on a new line. The thing is that each file has a unique string to be appened to its name. This is how i need it to work

> Run the find command
> Print the first result
> Have a read prompt for user to enter string , then append that string to the name.
> Print the second result.
> Have a read prompt .. then append that string to the second name
> ... and so on for all of the files

I have tried using while loop to do this , although haven't been successful yet

```
find . -type f -name 'file*' | 
  while IFS= read file_name; do 
    read -e -p "Enter your input : " string
    mv "$file_name" "$file_name $string" 
  done
```

For example. Lets say the original filename is demo1.mp4 , and i enter 'test' in the read prompt , then the filename should be renamed to 'demo1 test.mp4' ( There should be a space before appending the string to the end of filename )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do string slicing via [Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html), something like.

```
find . -type f -name 'file*' | {
  while IFS= read file_name; do
    name="${file_name%.*}"
    ext="${file_name#*"$name"}"
    read -e -p "Enter your input : " string </dev/tty
    echo mv "$file_name"  "$name $string$ext" 
  done
}
```

Since there are two `read`s inside the `while` loop, reading from `</dev/tty` is another work around, not sure if it is an O.S. specific or not but if it is available `/dev/tty` then it should fix the issue.

---

There are two `read` inside the `while loop` another approach is to use  [Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html), besides using `/dev/tty`

```
 while IFS= read -u9 file_name; do
    name="${file_name%.*}"
    ext="${file_name#*"$name"}"
    read -e -p "Enter your input : " string
    echo mv "$file_name"  "$name $string$ext" 
  done 9< <(find . -type f -name 'file*')
```

Remove the `echo` if you're satisfied with the output.

Some good examples are here [Howto Parameter Expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073)

Some good example of [Process Substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution).

Comment: Thanks for answer , i tried it but for some reason the read prompt is not working

Comment: Right, I have to move the parameter expansion just after the `do`, try it now.

Comment: I think something still is a miss , the read prompt never comes.   Check this out https://del.dog/raw/crirezutus

Comment: Yep, another `fd` for the first `read` should fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks , the solution at the bottom works flawlessly.  The one at top still doesn't work for some reason . I am marking it as accepted answer . ( You might possibly want to edit / remove the top one )

Comment: @Sachin, I have added a `</dev/tty` to the first answer which should fix the two `read`s issue as well, try it out as well.